# checkbox selection in chrome and IE

Tags: angular

I am currently working with one of the web application and having an issue regarding checkbox selection.
I am trying to make a checkbox selection in chrome and I am able to select it with single mouse click.But when i am trying the same in IE(internet explorer) it is getting selected only by multiple mouse clicks. so, is this how forms work in different browsers.?

Comment: No, that is not how forms work in IE. What version of IE you are using and Angular too.

Comment: IE-11, angular-4

Comment: IE-11 is supported with polyfills.ts. I highly recommend if you can to upgrade to the latest Angular version and check if it is the same.

Comment: okay thanks for that. will try and check